# Trigonometric proof/identity (real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $z+\frac{1}{z}=2cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is a real number. Then show that, for any integer $n$, $$z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}=2cos(n\theta)$$
My first thought was to use induction to achieve the conclusion but the manipulation does not reach the conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z+\frac1z=2\cos\theta$, then (since necessarily $z\neq 0$) $$z^2-2z\cos\theta+1=0$$ so that $$z=\cos\theta\pm\sqrt{\cos^2\theta-1}=\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta = e^{\pm i\theta}$$
Then (by DeMoivre)
$$z^n=e^{\pm in\theta}=\cos n\theta \pm i\sin n\theta$$
and $$z^{-n}=e^{\mp in\theta}=\cos n\theta \mp i\sin n\theta$$ so
$$z^n + \frac1{z^n}=2\cos n\theta$$ as desired. Note that the ambiguous sign for the square root does not matter in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can remark that $$(z^n+\frac{1}{z^n})(z+\frac{1}{z}) = (z^{n+1}+\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}) + (z^{n-1}+\frac{1}{z^{n-1}})$$

Hence, by induction $$(z^{n+1}+\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}) = 4\cos(n\theta)\cos(\theta)-2\cos((n-1)\theta).$$

Thanks to simpson's formula, you can see that this expression is equal to $2\cos((n+1)\theta).$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Write $z=r(\cos \alpha+i\sin \alpha$).

Find $\displaystyle z+\frac{1}{z}$ and compare with $2\cos \theta$ (you will learn that $r=1$).

Now consider $z^n=(\cos \alpha+i\sin \alpha)^n$ using De Moivre.

**Note:**  I see the real analysis tag... do you want $z$ to be real? The only real $z$ that do this are $\pm1$...

Comment: Why not $z = r(\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha)$?

Comment: @Kaster I probably should have done that yes (even if it does lead to $r=1$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $ z = e^{i \theta} $

It satisfies the given equations with and without exponentiation (through $n$).

Answer (score 0):

Because the product of $z$ by its inverse $\frac 1z$  is equal to $1$ we have

$z^2-2\cos \theta z+1=0\Rightarrow z=\cos \theta \pm\sqrt{\cos^2 \theta-1}=\cos \theta\pm i\sin \theta$.

Hence by Moivre $$z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}=\cos n\theta$$